# If the user has set a search filter, but the data is N/A, should it be shown

Tags: search, filter

For example,

Say the site is for searching cars for sale, one of the filters is "only show black cars", if there's a car listed which doesn't have a color specified, should it be included in the search results or not?

Comment: Might be worth repeating this comment from the asker on one of the answers: *"I am building an aggregator that pulls listings from a number of sites, some which have missing data (or don't enforce the data as a required field)"* - therefore, enforcing rules on data input alone isn't an answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some sites have "near miss" matches after their exact matches.

If a user has exhausted everything precisely matching their criteria but is still looking, there's a clear line and an explanation that this is the end of the results, then **"near misses"** sorted by how close to matching they are.

"Unspecified" would rank higher in this formula than "specified and wrong".

For example, it might look like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frA81v.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It's a good compromise because:

- You don't get potentially irrelevant results polluting the good results, which would make it look like the filter's broken or the site has poor quality control
- People who haven't found what they want after exhausting all the search results see things that might be relevant instead of a dead end
- In cases where there are no matches, people see at least something (this requires good labelling)
- Hard-to-match products that don't quite fit a taxonomy do get seen, and get seen by customers with hard-to-meet requirements

If there were no matches at all, you'd want a **VERY large**, prominent "Sorry, no results" box, around the size of those matches in the mockup above, so people don't see the (potentially relevant, potentially irrelevant) results before realising they're suggestions not matches, and then thinking something is broken.

Comment: This is a good approach. One situation it might not work as well for depends on how many results are going to be in the set. If there are many paginated pages of color-known results, would the unspecified results still be appended all the way at the end? I still like this solution, though.

Answer (score 9):

No. For the user to actively specify a color, then see colors which do not match their specification risks confusion and a lack of confidence in the accuracy of the tool.

An alternative would be to add a sub-category of "Unspecified".

If you want to do something really interesting, crowd-source the data in the Unspecified category and ask users to say what color the car is.

Comment: How will they see the colours that don't match? As OP said colour is unknown! You are assuming images are attached this might not be the case!

Comment: that did cross my mind actually, perhaps i'll give Amazon Mechanical Turk a go; https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome

Comment: It might also be worth looking into how Google Images's color filter works. Somehow when I search for "Car" then apply a color filter for "Blue" I'm given a whole bunch of obviously blue cars. You might be able to detect or at least make a "best guess" of what color those unspecified vehicles are and work them in.

Answer (score 3):

### Prioritize results with most relevant first:

You can mitigate the issue by:

- Displaying this category of cars at the bottom of your search results
  so cars that do meet the full search criteria are presented first
  (higher relevance), only caveat here is to **clearly emphasise visually
  and via adequate labelling** the results that do not match the colour
  criteria but tick all other requirements.
- Hiding the colour option within a collapsable filter

> It is perfectly acceptable to collapse filters to just a label,
>   providing a single link like View All Filters
>   Source: [Best Practices for Designing Faceted Search Filters](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/09/best-practices-for-designing-faceted-search-filters.php)

This will increase search accuracy and help conversions for the majority of users for whom colour is not the main focus. (approach used by Auto Trader)

[image]

---

### **Adding an option for unspecified or other ?**

Overall not a good idea, consider the following (assuming that product count is dynamicly updated as in the example of auto trader):

- When there is only limited number of cars with unspecified colour it
  would be a waste of precious page real-estate while also adding
  complexity to filtering options.
- When there is a large number of cars with unspecified attributes "colour or otherwise" then an unspecified option erodes user confidence in the site and indirectly suggests that your customers don't provide full details about what they are selling.

The best approach is to present your results with clarity using clear and understandable filtering options and ideally:

> “At every step in the search workflow, any visible filtering options
>   should reflect only the inventory that is available.”
>
> Source: [Best Practices for Designing Faceted Search Filters](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/09/best-practices-for-designing-faceted-search-filters.php)

Instead of burdining your filtering options with an ambiguous option, rely on users to make a judgment call if they would like to contact the vendor if the car ticks all their other requirements.

Overall, the unspecified or other option is an anomaly because "category labels should accurately describe the information in the category" to help users anticipate what they will find.

This might be the result of technical constraints as you have highlighted or because of difficulties matching the search criteria, but the user should not be asked to do guess work as a result:

> I am building an aggregator that pulls listings from a number of
>   sites, some which have missing data (or don't enforce the data as a
>   required field)

To conclude, **filtering options are not only a search facility but also a navigational structure** and labelling and navigation best practices should apply.

Comment: At first, I would go for that too but as a user, when I use a filter and it display me non related items, my though are : "well, these filter doesn't work well" and It tend to give me a bad feedback about a lot of things. I will use them anyway but with a feeling of bad experience, so If I find another website with good ones, it can make the difference. Can you force the user who create the classified ad ?

Comment: I somehow agree with @FrançoisDACQUIN; if the colour is unknown, the user *may* want to see the result, but it must be made *very* clear that "all results below this line" may or may not match the filter criteria. Possibly, don't even show those results immediately, but offer them via a link like "Show possible/unconfirmed matches". Google regularly thinks it knows better then me what I am looking for, and that auto-correction of search input regularly drives me crazy. No need to copy that bad habit for any filtering/search service.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I agree, unconfirmed matches should be clearly distinguished from other results!

Comment: How about using checkboxes or other such control to identify all "acceptable" controls, and have "other/unspecified" be one of the choices?

Comment: @supercat I think this approach could work looking at it from the mechanics point of view, however because the label is not clear enough and could even introduce uncertainty I wouldn't opt for it, I would rather explore options that focus more on presenting search results in a clearer and more interesting manner while also improving exploitability!

Comment: @Okavango: If, as in the case of color, most items will match one selection out of a fixed, but some items may not really match any, then "Other" is a perfectly meaningful choice.  Lumping in "unspecified" may ensure a user can always make a "correct" choice even if e.g. a car is a bluish-silver (in which case a user may be unclear whether that should be "blue", "silver", or "other", but could comfortably consider "other/unspecified" to be correct in any case)

Comment: Unfortunately my situation is unique in that I am building an aggregator that pulls listings from a number of sites, some which have missing data (or don't enforce the data as a required field) - hence why the long term solution couldn't really apply

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I undertand! nothing we can do here :)

Comment: @supercat : Auto Trader is a good example to consider, too many filters, and adding additional ones could only exasperate the situation ( Paradox of choice) Instead we should be asking how meaningful the option is and does it deserve a permanent spot in the filters. 'Let’s say I want to buy a red chair mat. Under Color, I can select the Red check box and view a great variety of red chair mats. Is there really a compelling reason for me to do anything else with the color filter?"[Read on](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/09/best-practices-for-designing-faceted-search-filters.php)

Comment: My point is that for something like "Color", regarding "Unspecified/Other" as no different from any other color will make it possible for a prospective buyer to search for a peach-colored car by clicking "Unspecified/other" along with "Orange" [or anything else a seller might call a peach-colored car].  While a search for "Unspecified/Other" would also turn up some other colors, most cars would have been classified as "red", "blue", etc. so searching through the pictures in the U/O category for one that looked peach would be a lot faster than looking through all the cars in the system.

Comment: @Okavango: [see above comment as well] A point I think many UI designers fail to consider is that what's more troublesome than having many choices is having choices that aren't quite "right".  Although increasing the number of choices may generally increase the number of users for whom the most accurate selection would be ambiguous, it is the latter quantity, rather than the number of users, which is problematic.  Someone who has to pick whether a peach-colored car is "orange" or "tan" may have a hard time choosing; allowing "other/unspecified" as a choice would ease the decision.

Comment: @supercat the argument could lead us down the rabbit hole☺ but, here is my take any way: what you are suggesting is definitely a valid point and will help some of the site users. That being said flexibility has always a price so you need to question if its really worth-it. Major players in this field either go very granular to satisfy all users (Auto trader - they have the means!) or very limited  (Motors) and I think the rationale is “we don’t want to cater for the lowest common denominator because it dilutes and complicates the experience for everyone else.

Comment: @supercat following on from the above, instead of embedding additional options in the site "structural elements" such as navigation and filters design should focus on knowing users better ( personalisation) and presenting results in a better way which was the point i tried to make in my answer. "Design theory maintains that over their lifecycle, systems shift from supporting multiple uses inefficiently, towards efficiently supporting a single use as users' needs become more defined and better understood, both by themselves and designers"

Comment: @Okavango: My point is that many awkward situations can be avoided by labeling the default as "unspecified/other" and regarding as a valid choice rather than a null value.  Since having the default behave as a valid choice is often no more difficult (it's often easier) than having it behave as null, it's good to handle it the same as any other choice absent a particular reason to do otherwise.  My point isn't that one should bend over backward to handle the awkward situations, but rather the opposite: if one can do something easy to avoid an awkward situation, one won't *have* to handle it.